# Unable to delete database using gcp cli

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

According to the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-databases#:%7E:text=To%20delete%20a%20database%2C%20use,you%20can%20delete%20the%20database.%5D=), you can delete a database by running the following:

```
gcloud alpha firestore databases delete --database="DATABASE NAME"
```

However, when I try to run the command, I get the following error message:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.alpha.firestore.databases) Invalid choice: 'delete'.
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The error implies you're running a version of gcloud CLI in which the command (option) isn't available/supported.
- Upgrade to the latest version of gcloud CLI (the alpha components)